# "two weeks' time" vs "two-week time"

Tags: possessives, numbers, apostrophe, noun-phrases

I know that:
**(1)** *in two weeks' time* - correct
**(2)** *in two-week time* - incorrect

But I don't know what will be without "*in*".
For example (my own sentences):
**(3)** ***Two weeks' time** is enough for a good vacation*.
**(4)** ***A two weeks' time** is enough for a good vacation*.
**(5)** ***The two weeks' time** is enough for a good vacation*.
**(6)** ***Two-week time** is enough for a good vacation*.
**(7)** ***A two-week time** is enough for a good vacation*.
**(8)** ***The two-week time** is enough for a good vacation*.

Which of them are correct and which are not and why?

P.S.: I understand that the following is correct:
**(9)** **Two weeks** is enough for a good vacation.

Comment: Interesting question! I'm not sure why, but (3) through (8) are all wrong. We simply would add the word "time" in the context. So (1) and (9) are the only correct choices.

Comment: **In two weeks time** means 'two weeks from now', not 'a period of two weeks'.

Comment: 'Two weeks' time', 'a two-week period'.